# Calculating the integral while finding distribution of random variable $Z=Y-X$.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> We have $$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le 0 \\x & 0 < x \le 1  \\ 1 & x > 1 \end{cases}$$
> $$F_T(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le 0 \\ \dfrac{x}{2} & 0 < x \le 2  \\ 1 & x > 2 \end{cases}$$
> for two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Find the distribution of $Z = Y-X$.

I have figured out that
$$F_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_Y(z+x)dF_X(x)$$
but splitting the integral and calculating confuses me. The existence of $z$ makes it more difficult. Any help on calculating the integral is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $\dfrac{\mathrm d F_\xi(x)}{\mathrm d x} = \mathbf 1_{0<x\leqslant 1} $ and $F_\eta(z+x) = \dfrac{z+x}{2}\mathbf 1_{0 < z+x\leqslant 2}+\mathbf 1_{2<z+x}$ so

$\qquad\begin{align}F_\zeta(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_\eta(z+x),\mathrm dF_\xi(x)\\[1ex]&=\int_0^1 \left(\dfrac{z+x}{2}\mathbf 1_{0 < z+x\leqslant 2}+\mathbf 1_{2<z+x}\right)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{-1<z\leqslant 2}\int_{\max(0,-z)}^{\min(1,2-z)} \dfrac{z+x}{2}\,\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{1<z\leqslant 2}\int_{\max(0,2-z)}^1\,\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{2<z}\\[2ex]&=\begin{cases}0&:&\qquad~~~ z\leqslant -1\\[1ex] \underline\qquad &:& -1<z\leqslant 0\\[1ex]\underline\qquad &:&~~~0<z\leqslant 1\\[1ex]\underline\qquad&:& ~~~1<z\leqslant 2\\[1ex]1&:&~~~2<z \end{cases}\end{align}$

Comment: How are you choosing the intervals for $z$ at the end?

Comment: Based on how the min and max values behave relative to changing $z$.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not clear, drawing a diagram may help.

I will use $X$ instead of $\xi$ and $Y$ instead of $\eta$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with CDF given as below -

$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le 0 \\x & 0 < x \le 1  \\ 1 & x > 1 \end{cases}$

$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 0 & y \le 0 \\ \dfrac{y}{2} & 0 < y \le 2  \\ 1 & y > 2 \end{cases}$

We need to find distribution of $Z = Y - X$.

As $f_X(x) = 1, 0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2}, 0 \leq y \leq 2$, we have a uniform distribution over $[0,1] \times [0,2]$

[image]

we can find CDF either by geometrically calculating area below line $z = y - x$ or set up an integral. Also see the lines $z = y - x = 0, z = y - x = 1$ drawn in bold.

Clearly, $ \displaystyle F_Z(z) = 0, \ \ z \leq -1 $.

i) For a line $z = y - x$ below $z = 0$ ($ - 1 \lt z \leq 0$), area is bound between x-axis, $x = 1$ and $z = y - x$. At $y = 0, x = -z$ so $-z \leq x \leq 1$

So, $ \displaystyle F_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-z}^1 (z+x) dx = \frac{(z+1)^2}{4}$, $-1 \lt z \leq 0$.

ii) For a line $z$ between $ 0 \lt z \leq 1$, area is bound between y-axis, $x = 1$, x-axis and $z = y - x$.

So, $ \displaystyle F_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 (z+x) dx = \frac{2z+1}{4}$, $0 \lt z \leq 1$.

iii) For a line $z$ between $ 1 \lt z \leq 2$, it is easier to find area between y-axis, $z = y - x$ and $y = 2$ and subtract from total area.

So, $ \displaystyle F_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2} \bigg[2 - \int_0^{2-z} (2 - (z+x)) dx\bigg] = z - \frac{z^2}{4}$, $1 \lt z \leq 2$.

Lastly, $ \displaystyle F_Z(z) = 1, \ \ z \gt 2 $

Comment: "At $y=0,~x=-z$ so $-z \le x \le 1$"... I couldn't get the general clue of finding the bounds for $x$ in such way, sorry.

Comment: OK given $z = y - x$, do you see $z = 0 \implies y = x$ line drawn in green? Now if $z \lt 0$ the line will be below it. I have drawn a line to show it. How do you find area below that line? The line intersects x-axis and $x = 1$. When it is intersecting x-axis, $y = 0$ at that point. so given $z = y - x$ and $y = 0, x = - z$ at that point. Now I am taking vertical strip below line $z = y - x$ and that vertical length is $y = z + x$ and then I am integrating over dx to find area. We could do without integral too.