# Confusion in calculating $\int_0^2 \left( \frac{z-x}{2}\mathbf 1_{0 \le z- x \le 2} + \mathbf 1_{2 < z-x}\right)\text dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, cumulative-distribution-functions

While calculating the CDF of a sum of random variables (as opposed to a difference in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147612/calculating-the-integral-while-finding-distribution-of-random-variable-z-y-x)), I came to the following integral
$$\int_0^2 \left( \frac{z-x}{2}\mathbf 1_{0 \le z- x \le 2} + \mathbf 1_{2 < z-x}\right)\text dx$$
But I cannot figure out how to choose the intervals for $z$ as in the linked answer.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you are stuck on? I am not sure if your question is about computing the integral or proving that the CDF is equal to the integral. By the way, if you are talking about the integral from the linked post, then the upper bound is different here than in the accepted answer there.

Comment: @Carlo Yes, it is a different problem from the linked post. While trying to find CDF in this particular problem, I came to this integral and now got stuck here.

Comment: If your question is about integration, then I think you should change the tags to prioritize that.

Comment: In other question you were finding CDF for $Z = Y - X$ and here you are finding for $Z = X + Y$. Till you are confident about it, start by drawing a diagram. If you learn how to do that for such questions, you will get it right.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $0 \leq z - x \leq 2$ if and only if $-z \leq -x \leq 2 - z$ if and only if $z - 2 \leq x \leq z.$ Consequently, the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{0 \leq z - x \leq 2}$ can be identified with the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{z - 2 \leq x \leq z}.$ By definition of the integral, we have that $0 \leq x \leq 2,$ hence if $x$ does not satisfy $x \geq \max \{0, z - 2\},$ then the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{0 \leq z - x \leq 2}$ will be zero. By a similar rationale, if $x$ does not satisfy $x \leq \min \{2, z\},$ then the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{0 \leq z - x \leq 2}$ will be zero. Last, we have that $x \leq z \leq x + 2,$ from which it follows that $0 \leq z \leq 4.$ Ultimately, this analysis yields $$\int_0^2 {\left(\frac{z - x} 2 \mathbf 1_{0 \leq z - x \leq 2} + \mathbf 1_{2 < z - x} \right)} \, dx = \mathbf 1_{0 \leq z \leq 4} \int_{\max \{0, z - 2\}}^{\min \{2, z\}} \frac{z - x} 2 \, dx + \int_0^2 \mathbf 1_{2 < z - x} \, dx.$$ Can you perform a similar analysis for the second integral to complete the problem?